# Lorentz Invariant Equation of Motion for Scalar Field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, mathematical-physics, field-theory

I'm trying to understand why you can't write down a first order equation of motion for a scalar field in special relativity.

Suppose $\phi(x)$ a scalar field, $v^{\mu}$ a 4-vector. According to my notes a quantity of form $v^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\phi(x)$ will not be Lorentz invariant.

But explicitly doing the active transformation the quantity becomes

$$\Lambda^{\mu}_{\nu} v^{\nu}(\Lambda^{-1})^{\rho}_{\mu}\partial_{\rho}\phi(y) = v^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}\phi(y)$$

where $y=\Lambda^{-1}x$ and the partial differentiation is w.r.t. $y$. This seems to suggest that the quantity is a Lorentz scalar, so could be used to construct a Lorentz invariant first order equation of motion.

I'm clearly making a mistake here. But I don't see what I've done wrong. Am I wrong to think that $v$ transforms nontrivially under the active transformation? Maybe it shouldn't transform at all because it's just a vector, not a vector field?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your notes seem wrong. If $v^\mu$ is a 4-vector, then $v^\mu \partial_\mu = v \cdot \partial$ is indeed a Lorentz scalar.

Comment: @Vibert - then we could get a first order equation of motion for a scalar field though... Isn't that a problem?

Comment: You would only be able to get $v^\mu = x^\mu$ (what else?), and I don't think such a term could come from applying Euler-Lagrange to a translation-invariant Lagrangian. It's probably a good exercise to see if it's possible!

Comment: Why can't you choose $v^{\mu}$ to be another arbitrary four vector?

Comment: @Vibert $v^\mu=x^\mu$ is no less arbitrary than $v^\mu=(1,2,3,\text{cos}(x^2))$ since the origin is arbitrary anyway.

Comment: Field equations are local, i.e. they are of the form $D \phi (x) = 0$ where $D$ is some differential operator. So $D$ could depend on $x$. However, if you use any other point $y \neq x$, you're fixing some preferred point in space, thereby breaking translation invariance. (What I mean is: the Green's function would depend on $y^\mu$.)

Comment: @sjasonw: you are correct, but I think your argument isn't optimal. The argument is that $\mathcal{L}$ cannot depend on position explicitly, and therefore the EOM will not depend on $x^\mu.$ The $v^\mu$ you're proposing isn't a four-vector, so it confuses the argument.

Comment: @Vibert On the 4-vector issue that you pointed out:  It can be made a 4-vector by taking the form I wrote down in some starting frame and then demanding the vector transformation law for other frames.  It's totally arbitrary, but all I was trying to say was that $x$ isn't the only 4-vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $v^a \partial_a \phi$ *is* a scalar field.  Nonetheless, an equation like this is ugly because $v^a$ points in some "preferred" direction.

Here's another point of view, and I think this gets at what you were saying about "no first order equations".  Suppose that $v^a$ is *not* a vector but is instead just a collection of four fixed real numbers.  Suppose we consider the equation $\sum _\mu v^\mu \partial_\mu \phi=0$ now.  This equation is not Lorentz invariant anymore since the numbers $v^\mu$ don't change.

Another approach:  think of $v^a$ as a new spacetime-dependent vector field.  Then, $v^a \partial_a \phi=0$ is Lorentz invariant equation, but it involves two fields.  This is nicer than choosing a preferred direction.

Comment: Aha this is the insight I was looking for. Think I was on the right lines in the question when I said it didn't transform because it wasn't a field. Cheers!